# Django not response to Ajax call while doing a computing intensive task

Tags: python, ajax, django, asynchronous, backend

I am recently using `Django` to program my web interface for my "scientific computing engine".

I wrap the "computing engine" as a python module and call it inside the Django Framework.

The `compute()` function of the "engine" takes several minutes to run (I use `ajax` to trigger it) , at the same time, I let the front-end make extra `ajax` call every 0.5 second to update the CPU and Memory status to the front-end. But I find the server is not respond to the extra `ajax` call until the `compute()` finishes.

After search around, I think I might use the idea of `asynchronous` or `multithreading`

so I make the function in `views.py` like below.

`def submit(request):
     #some prepare
     ........
     # call the engine
     t = Thread(target = compute)
     t.start()
     return HttpResponse("started")`

But the system still not response to my extra `ajax` call until the `compute()` finish (The "engine" only use around 20% of the CPU, so there is plenty of computing power left).

I am a newbie in back-end programming, I am not sure about how `Django` or backend server handle request internally. 
Thank you so much if anyone can give me some hint about how to handle this situation.

Comment: You might want to look into things like Celery.

Comment: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#using-celery-with-django

Answer (score 1):

It's never a good idea to start threads from views like that.

The most common way to solve this is to delegate the work to a separate worker/process. In addition to django you have another python process looking for work.

You can keep it simple and make the Django view store information about the work that needs to be done in some format on disk or in a database (this would be the work queue). Then the worker process will run in a loop checking for available work every N seconds. Increase the number of workers/processes to add more computing power (limited by your hardware of course)

The http request that creates the work request can return a `job_id` the user can query to get the status of the job. Is the job pending/in progress/done? Then maybe the user can also fetch the result of the job or even metadata such as duration and logs?

There are also frameworks out there to solve problems like this such as Celery and django-channels. Celery is probably easier to start with, but it might be overkill for what you are trying to do.

The advantage of using workers like this is that you can have a very light weight REST api in the front and you can scale up the number of workers, possibly across multiple servers as the demand increases.

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved this problem by using python `subprocess`

I make my "compute" code in a separate file and use the `Popen` to call it.

`from subprocess import Popen
def submit(request):
     #some prepare
     ........
     # call the engine
     p = Popen(["python", "compute.py", <arguments>])
     return HttpResponse("started")`

However as suggested, `subprocess` is not a very good and safe practice. This solution is easy to realize but I will try to convert the back-end to `worker mode` by using `Celery` or  `django-channels` as @Grimmy suggested.

Comment: I suggest using Celery for now as the project is mature, stable and well documented. If you have very simple requirements you can also just make a storage for the data communicated between the api and the worker not having to add all the extra stuff required by Celery.